# Why does Python regex with literal words not match, but \w+ does?

Tags: python, regex, typography

I tried to write a regular expression that looks like it would work, but I had to replace some of the literal strings with word patterns and I want to understand why.

Here's the example:

```
import re

text = "   1    p2       2.26347691E+12    optvl    9.05369210E+04    ctha     6.00000000E+01"

p1 = re.compile(r"\s+(\d+)\s+p2\s+([\d\.\+\-E]+)\s+optv1\s+([\d\.\+\-E]+)\s+ctha\s+([\d\.\+\-E]+)")
m1 = p1.findall(text)
print m1

p2 = re.compile(r"\s+(\d+)\s+p2\s+([\d\.\+\-E]+)\s+\w+\s+([\d\.\+\-E]+)\s+\w+\s+([\d\.\+\-E]+)")
m2 = p2.findall(text)
print m2
```

Here's the output:

```
[]
[('1', '2.26347691E+12', '9.05369210E+04', '6.00000000E+01')]
```

Thanks for any insight!

Edit: yep, it's a typo - the old `l` vs `1`

Comment: `optvl` versus `optv1`.  You've got a typo.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Surely in that case this is off-topic?

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I get for not switching my fonts back to something that distinguishes characters better after a recent reinstall.

Comment: @AlexThornton - Likely.  Mine is one of the close votes for that reason.

Comment: I added typography tag if that helps, lol, though I don't care if it's closed - my problem is solved and this doesn't help anyone other than a cautionary tale - nevermind, reading the off-topic message I totally understand, should definitely be closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in the first version with words, should be `l` instead of `1`:

```
p1 = re.compile(r"\s+(\d+)\s+p2\s+([\d\.\+\-E]+)\s+optvl\s+([\d\.\+\-E]+)\s+ctha\s+([\d\.\+\-E]+)")
                                                       ^
```

Comment: Drats! I had to re-install everything a while back and I haven't re-installed Source Code Pro yet too help distinguish similar characters. Thanks - it's not letting me accept for a few more minutes apparently, but I will in a bit.